# Images differs in chrome and mozilla

Tags: html, css, image

The same image which looks perfect in Mozilla and imperfect when browsed in Chrome.  Here are the images.  Can anyone suggest me why these types of bugs and how to solve it.

The first is Mozilla and second is Chrome.

[image: Mozilla][image: Chrome]

The CSS Code is,

```
.freeimg
{
    position            : relative;
    top                 : 80px;
    border              : 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right        : 0;
    background-color    : #FFF;
    cursor              :  pointer;
    margin-left         : -35px;
    -moz-border-radius  : 10px 0px  0px 10px;
}
```

The HTML Code is normal as usual.

```
<div class="fl freeimg" style="float:left;">
 <img src="/images/freeImg.gif" height="160" width="32" onClick="SlideMe()" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is your code? Somebody elses? Some random site you saw it on? Can you post the code either way?

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan okay sure. :)

Comment: Add your html also or else you can create a fiddle

Comment: oh yeah. https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6928617728/hA937289F/

Comment: BTW is there any reason why `-moz-border-radius  : 10px 0px  0px 10px;` is left alone? If you want the border-radius in all browsers including chrome just do `border-radius  : 10px 0px  0px 10px;` .

Comment: By the way prasobh and Rithu are pretty good. You could use them to display the height less in pixels and adjust it if it detects Chrome.

Comment: @DumbProducts Though those answers seems to be correct practically it fails.  I have one more idea to make it work.  i.e., Giving green background to that area by changing css code as: background-color    : #<green color>;  But i want to learn.  These things not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change css dynamically for this purpose use javascript check condition

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
 // modify button 
}
```

under this give your css change only for chrome

Answer (score 2):

Add `font-size:0`

**HTML**

```
<div class="fl freeimg">
 <img src="http://www.brightpay.co.uk/i/signup-launcher.png" onClick="SlideMe()" />
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
 .freeimg
{
    position            : relative;
    float:left;
    top                 : 80px;
    border              : 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right        : 0;
    background-color    : #FFF;
    cursor              :  pointer;
    border-radius  : 10px 0px  0px 10px;
    font-size:0
}    
.freeimg img
{        
    border-radius  : 10px 0px  0px 10px;
     margin:0; padding:0
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4HuWf/4/)**

Comment: Thankyou for your reply sowmya.  Though this works in fiddle it fails for me.!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a CSS reset first by loading a stylesheet such as the one explained here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Browser have different *defaults*, and unless you overwrite these values with your own settings, they may still apply. In your particular case, I would try adding:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

and see if that removes the differences. But using a `reset.css` as explained above is a best practise to avoid this kind of differences.

Comment: Oh, and why are you using `-moz-border-radius`?

Comment: No specific reason.  First i checked on mozilla and later i checked with chrome.   if i remove that row it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write conditional css comments to solve this type of problem. This is nothing but a css problem. Please post your code. May be it will be useful for solving this problem

Like the below code

Inspect element in firefox and adjust the css style seperate css file for firefox browser and add the code below

if ( $.browser.mozilla == true ) {
      document.write("");
    }